# libGDX java PC game: Which gradlew/OpenJDK versions to use

Tags: java, libgdx, 32bit-64bit, gradlew, launch4j

I'm working on a project that started to develop in 2014.
Now the game is almost ready and we decided to move on to OpenJDK.

The problem is that I fail to synchronize versions. Our gradlew version is **2.12**, gdxVersion **1.9.2**.

I started from **OpenJDK 14** and tried to increase versions of all the libraries we use gradlew, launch4j, prougard, gdxVersion, johnrengelman.shadow, gson ...
And after a lot of pain I had a feeling I was spinning in a circle.

So, I gave up on the idea of changing our project and looked for an OpenJDK that would work.
It turned out to be **OpenJDK 8**. But it is very old, and has only a **32-bit version**. We don't want to be limited to 32 bits...

Update:
*I was unable to find 64-bit version for Windows on the official site.(https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/) And I’m not sure how smart it is to stick to that version.*

I wonder what you suggest in these situations where to start?

Whether to start from libGDX 1.9.10? Which version of OpenJDK?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to upgrade project.

The versions I used:

1. openjdk version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
2. gdxVersion = '1.9.10'
3. Gradle 5.1.1
4. 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.2.0'
5. 'edu.sc.seis.launch4j' version '2.4.6'

It was necessary to slightly modify the **build.gradle** files.